# Check if address is full in Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I need to check if given address is full or not. I'm using Google Maps API v3 autocomplete in one of my fields and when address is selected, three other fields are populated. Fields: City, Street name, House.

When I select full address, everything works fine. But if I, for example, not enter house number, I get wrong results. City becomes parish, Street becomes city, House becomes street.

Question is: **how to check if given address is full or how to select required address components by not [0], [1] etc, but ['city'], ['street'] etc?**

Code:

```
<script>
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.169438, 23.881275),
            zoom: 7,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);

        var input = document.getElementById('searchMap');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
            infowindow.close();
            marker.setVisible(false);
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            if (!place.geometry) {
                $("#CityName").attr("readonly", false);
                $("#StreetName").attr("readonly", false);
                $("#House").attr("readonly", false);
                $("#ExternalId").attr("readonly", false);
                return;
            }
            $("#CityName").attr("readonly", true);
            $("#StreetName").attr("readonly", true);
            $("#House").attr("readonly", true);
            $("#ExternalId").attr("readonly", true);

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
                map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                map.setZoom(17);
            }
            var image = {
                url: place.icon,
                size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
            };
            marker.setIcon(image);
            marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
            marker.setVisible(true);

            var address = '';
            if (place.address_components) {
                address = [
                    (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                    (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                    (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
                ].join(' ');
                $('#House').val(place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || '');
                $('#StreetName').val(place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || '');
                $('#CityName').val(place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '');
                $('#ExternalId').val(place.id);
            }
            infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: show us some code. we can't read your mind

Comment: did you fix this? Wow this is old

Comment: As far as I can remember, we did not solve it properly and went hack-ways. Unfortunately, not working at the company anymore, and I do not really remember the "solution".